# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2 python

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, shapes

I am trying to perform decision trees with some train and test data which are in lists named x&y.
my train data x is this:

```
[array([[19. , 14. ,  0.8],
   [23. , 24. ,  0.8],
   [25. , 26. ,  0.8],
   [22. , 24. ,  1. ],
   [25. , 29. ,  1.4],
   [36. , 86. ,  1.6],
   [28. , 52. ,  0.8],
   [21. , 20. ,  1. ],
   [22. , 28. ,  0.8],
   [24. , 27. ,  1. ],
   [18. ,  8. ,  0.6],
   [30. , 58. ,  1.2],
   [24. , 30. ,  0.8],
   [24. , 28. ,  0.8],
   [32. , 65. ,  1.6],
   [28. , 47. ,  0.8],
   [26. , 41. ,  0.8],
   [18. , 14. ,  0.6],
   [32. , 71. ,  2.2],
   [27. , 45. ,  2. ],
   [29. , 53. ,  2.2],
   [18. , 11. ,  0.8],
   [20. , 23. ,  0.8],
   [20. , 19. ,  0.6],
   [20. , 15. ,  0.6],
   [19. , 18. ,  0.4],
   [24. , 55. ,  1.2],
   [24. , 59. ,  1. ],
   [20. , 17. ,  0.6],
   [21. , 28. ,  0.8]])]
```

and y:

```
[array([ 3100.,  2750.,  7800.,  6000., 15000., 15500.,  5600.,  8000.,
    6000.,  7500.,  4000.,  9000.,  5850.,  5750., 18000.,  5600.,
    5600.,  4500., 22000., 21500., 24000.,  4000.,  6000.,  4000.,
    8000.,  8000., 14000., 14000.,  6000.,  4000.])]
```

when i try to perform

```
dtree= DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0, max_depth=1)
dtree.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I get the error `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.` and couldn't solve it with reshape since these are lists. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to convert X and Y as `numpy` arrays, but I can not be 100% sure if your variables are indeed, since you haven't uploaded your code here. Secondly, take a look at your variables. As it says in the [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.fit):

> X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)

AND

> yarray-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)

`fit` function expects 2D arrays in both `X` and `Y` arrays. And `X_train` is 3D.

So you need to reshape these two. One solution can be:

**AMSWER EDITTED AFTER READING HIS/HER COMMENTS**

The reason why you can't train your data is because 2 things:

- `X_train` has a bad shape
- `Y_train` has a bad shape

Your are passing a 3D array with `X_train`, and `fit` only allows you to be 2D. Furthermore, your `Y_train` has shape `(1, 30)` which means you are passing 30 data at once. You need to separate them and passing as `(30, )`, as follows:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import numpy as np

X_train = np.array([np.array([[19. , 14. ,  0.8],
   [23. , 24. ,  0.8],
   [25. , 26. ,  0.8],
   [22. , 24. ,  1. ],
   [25. , 29. ,  1.4],
   [36. , 86. ,  1.6],
   [28. , 52. ,  0.8],
   [21. , 20. ,  1. ],
   [22. , 28. ,  0.8],
   [24. , 27. ,  1. ],
   [18. ,  8. ,  0.6],
   [30. , 58. ,  1.2],
   [24. , 30. ,  0.8],
   [24. , 28. ,  0.8],
   [32. , 65. ,  1.6],
   [28. , 47. ,  0.8],
   [26. , 41. ,  0.8],
   [18. , 14. ,  0.6],
   [32. , 71. ,  2.2],
   [27. , 45. ,  2. ],
   [29. , 53. ,  2.2],
   [18. , 11. ,  0.8],
   [20. , 23. ,  0.8],
   [20. , 19. ,  0.6],
   [20. , 15. ,  0.6],
   [19. , 18. ,  0.4],
   [24. , 55. ,  1.2],
   [24. , 59. ,  1. ],
   [20. , 17. ,  0.6],
   [21. , 28. ,  0.8]])])

dimX1, dimX2, dimX3 = np.array(X_train).shape
X_train = np.reshape(np.array(X_train), (dimX1*dimX2, dimX3))

Y_train = np.array([np.array([ 3100.,  2750.,  7800.,  6000., 15000., 15500.,  5600.,  8000.,
    6000.,  7500.,  4000.,  9000.,  5850.,  5750., 18000.,  5600.,
    5600.,  4500., 22000., 21500., 24000.,  4000.,  6000.,  4000.,
    8000.,  8000., 14000., 14000.,  6000.,  4000.])])

dimY1, dimY2 = Y_train.shape
Y_train = np.reshape(np.array(Y_train), (dimY2, ))

print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape)
dtree= DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0, max_depth=1)
dtree.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Its output is:

```
>>> (30, 3) (30,)

>>> DecisionTreeRegressor(ccp_alpha=0.0, criterion='mse', max_depth=1,
                      max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                      min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                      min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                      min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                      random_state=0, splitter='best')
```

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'" error with that solution :/

Comment: well, that means you dont have `X_train ` as a `numpy` array. Check my editted answer now!

Comment: i added X_train = np.array(x_train) to have it as a numpy array now, and it gives the error "Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2."again . my lists are in the question you can check them if you want. there are 90 values, i dont know if its the case, just wanted to mention it

Comment: i think y _train is already 2d cause when i try to apply dim1, dim2, dim3 = np.array(Y_train).shape, received "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)" error

Comment: it says X_train's shape is (3,30) and y_train's is (1,30)